# how can I use axios patch to send an empty request body?

Tags: axios, request, postman

I am making a PATCH request with Axios that gives me the behavior I need when the request body is set to 'none' on Postman.

However, on the frontend, when I try to use 'null' or 'undefined' or '{}', the server always returns a 500 error.  Is there another way to replicate the "none" request body of Postman?

Comment: Have you tried an empty string e.g ""?

Comment: I have tried that also, not working